# how to have iptables NAT like setup on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to replicate a server to AWS. It is a simple web server running with **non-root ID listening on port 8080 and 8443**.  There're **iptables** rules which "nat" the traffic to port 80 and 443 to 8080 and 8443

```
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

How can I set it up with EC2 ? My instance setup is having just one simple VPC.

Thanks
W

Comment: Why can't you just use the same `iptables` configuration on your EC2 instance?

Comment: The security group is the "simple firewall".  I was thinking may be there's another way to do the NAT.  Sure. I think another level of iptables is OK. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what you're trying to achieve, including any details of ports,  environments, and network archtiecture. I suspect you're looking for some kind of a firewall. In AWS you use security groups for this.